Flutter: How get real time in flutter app?
I have created a flutter app and I need the time for calculating future but cannot get actual time i.e. DateTime.timestamp() showing the time 11:23 but in device showing the time 15:51 my device is Galaxy A20s.

The difference that you see with timestamp is because that is in the UTC timezone. While your phone would be set to your timezone.

Can you get the time to Pakistan timezone

The answer Moon Princess gave would do that for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/78807024/10878426

DateTime now = DateTime.now(); 

You can use this for current time, I hope this may help you.

This gets me the right value, including timezone offset:
final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
final String formattedTime = DateFormat.yMd().add_jms().format(now);
print(formattedTime);

You may have to change the DateFormat for your locale.

This seems like a very over complicated example. With only DateTime now = DateTime.now(); It would also solve the question asked
